# Import multiple excel files, create a column and get values from excel file's name

Tags: python, pandas

I need to upload multiple excel files - each one has a name of starting date. Eg. "20190114".
Then I need to append them in one DataFrame.
For this, I use the following code:

```
all_data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in glob.glob('C:\\path\\*.xlsx'):
df = pd.read_excel(f)
all_data = all_data.append(df,ignore_index=True)
```

In fact, I do not need all data, but filtered by multiple columns.
Then, I would like to create an additional column ('from') with values of file name (which is "date") for each respective file.

Example:

Data from the excel file, named **'20190101'**

[image]

Data from the excel file, named **'20190115'**

[image]

The final dataframe must have values in 'price' column not equal to '0' and in code column - with code='r' (**I do not know if it's possible to export this data already filtered**, avoiding exporting huge volume of data?) and then I need to add a column 'from' with the respective date coming from file's name:

like this:

[image]

dataframes for trial:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':['id_1', 'id_2','id_3', 'id_4','id_5'],
               'price':[0,12.5,17.5,24.5,7.5],
               'code':['r','r','r','c','r'] })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id':['id_1', 'id_2','id_3', 'id_4','id_5'],
               'price':[7.5,24.5,0,149.5,7.5],
               'code':['r','r','r','c','r'] })
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can  filter necessary rows ,then concat, for file name you can use `os.path.split()` and access the filename with string slicing:

```
l=[]
for f in glob.glob('C:\\path\\*.xlsx'):
    df=pd.read_excel(f)
    df['from']=os.path.split(f)[1][:-5]
    l.append(df[(df['code'].eq('r')&df['price'].ne(0))])
pd.concat(l,ignore_index=True)
```

---

```
     id  price code      from
0  id_2   12.5    r  20190101
1  id_3   17.5    r  20190101
2  id_5    7.5    r  20190101
3  id_1    7.5    r  20190115
4  id_2   24.5    r  20190115
5  id_5    7.5    r  20190115
```

Comment: Thank you @anky_91! it's working! I just needed to exclude those that are not equal to 'r', but it's easy to fix

Comment: @Vero sorry for missing that out, fixed the code now :)