# Add a date column to dataframe based on another date column

Tags: python, pandas

In the previous [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58543280/import-multiple-excel-files-create-a-column-and-get-values-from-excel-files-na#58543366) I have obtained a column "from" in the date format - **20190101**.
I need to add the column "to" based on the column "from".
Basically the range is like this:

from 20190101 to 20190114

from 20190115 to 20190131

from 20190201 to 20190215

from 20190215 to 20190228

etc

How can I automatize this?

How to treat data as dates and operate on them. Eg., I have a date 20181231, I want to add a day 20181231 + 1 = 20190101

Comment: Is input data column `from` ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data are those from the linked question:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': {1: 'id_2', 2: 'id_3', 3: 'id_4', 4: 'id_5', 0: 'id_1'},
                   'price': {1: 24.5, 2: 17.5, 3: 149.5, 4: 7.5, 0: 7.5},
                   'code': {1: 'r', 2: 'r', 3: 'c', 4: 'r', 0: 'r'},
                   'from': {1: 20190115, 2: 20190101, 3: 20190115, 4: 20190115, 0: 20190115}})

df["from"] = pd.to_datetime(df["from"],format="%Y%m%d")

df["to"] = df["from"]+pd.DateOffset(days=14)

print (df)

#
     id  price code       from         to
1  id_2   24.5    r 2019-01-15 2019-01-29
2  id_3   17.5    r 2019-01-01 2019-01-15
3  id_4  149.5    c 2019-01-15 2019-01-29
4  id_5    7.5    r 2019-01-15 2019-01-29
0  id_1    7.5    r 2019-01-15 2019-01-29
```

Comment: Thank you @Henry Yik. Is it possible to change a format to 20190101 in the final version. Or it's not a date format but just a string?

Comment: It’s a dtype of datetime but you can use `strftime` to construct your desired format by `Series.dt.strftime(“%Y%m%d”)`.

Comment: I have a question - for the second fortnight of each month it's important that the column "to" is filled with the last day of the month which is not happening for February. Ho to fix it?

Comment: `df["to"] = df["from"]+pd.offsets.MonthEnd()` to get the last day of a month.

Answer (score 1):

As in your example

```
df:    
        from
0 2019-01-01
1 2019-01-15
2 2019-02-01
3 2019-02-15
```

You need subtract 1 day from column `from` and shift backward and `fillna`

```
df['to'] = ((df['from'] - pd.DateOffset(1)).shift(-1)
                                           .fillna(df['from'].tail(1) + 
                                                   pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)))

Out[753]:
        from         to
0 2019-01-01 2019-01-14
1 2019-01-15 2019-01-31
2 2019-02-01 2019-02-14
3 2019-02-15 2019-02-28
```

Comment: Great @Andy L! Exactly what I need. It works for months like February with 28 days.